# Visual Studio 2019: how to configure the default CLR for the debugger?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, f#, clr

I recently installed Visual Studio 2019 on Windows with .NET 5 and .NET Core 3.1 (I did not install any .NET Framework SDK, but seems to be a dependency of other stuff I installed). I decided to create a test F# .NET Core 3.1 project, below is the `.csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Name>FSharpSample</Name>
    <ProjectGuid>{be6b33ca-c77e-49de-af02-5febd314d410}</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>true</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
    <RemoteDebugEnabled>false</RemoteDebugEnabled>
    <StartAction>Project</StartAction>
    <EnableSQLServerDebugging>false</EnableSQLServerDebugging>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>true</UseVSHostingProcess>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to start debugging the process using the "Start" button in Visual Studio 2019, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Starting the project without a debugger and attaching a debugger to the running process with the "Managed (.NET Core, .NET 5+) code" options works however. For reference, these are my installed components:

[image]

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: I'm frequently switching between .NET core projects and .NET Framework projects and the debugger "just works". Have you installed the .NET Core SDK system wide? (download from aka.ms/dotnet-download)

Comment: You are right, I just noticed only .NET 5 was installed but not .NET Core 3.1. I will give that a shot and come back.

Comment: No dice, still not working after installing .NET Core 3.1.

`PS C:\Users\Vlad\source\repos\Autonomous-Car-Simulator> dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.407 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]`

Comment: Bad :( Does it work if you create a .NET core C# app? F# is maybe less well tested.

Comment: Very interesting... For C# it tells me that I'm "missing features". The missing feature is .NET Desktop Environment. Strange, I thought the SDK should be enough.

Comment: Hah, sure enough works right now after installation. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to install .NET Desktop Environment feature for Visual Studio 2019. I do not know why it is needed, I thought the SDK would suffice, so please clarify if you know.